# How to add text to display for a Hyperlink in Excel Spreadsheet Using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create a worksheet wherein you enter the web address of a site say ex: http://www.google.com and upon entering the value, the cell should display only “XYZ” and not the entire web address. Upon clicking that cell, it should take us to that site.

Below is the sample vb script

```
Dim objExcel

Set objExcel = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = TRUE
objExcel.Workbooks.Open "C:\\bintest.xls"
objExcel.Workbooks(1).Activate
objExcel.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1)
Set objRange = objExcel.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1)
Dim sLinkAddress
sLinkAddress = "http://www.google.com"
Set objLink = objWorksheet.Hyperlinks.Add(objRange,sLinkAddress)
objExcel.Workbooks(1).SaveAs "C:\\bintest.xls"
objExcel.Quit
```

How to display XYZ instead of entire web address . Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the `HYPERLINK()` worksheet function.

```
objExcel.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "=HYPERLINK(""http://www.google.com"", ""XYZ"")"

' Or, to use variables instead...
objExcel.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "=HYPERLINK(""" & sLinkAddress & """,""" & sFriendly & """)"
```

Or, you can use the method you're currently using. Use the 5th param to specify the "friendly name" of the URL.

```
objExcel.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add objRange, "http://www.google.com", , , "XYZ"
```

Comment: Bond, are two double quotes required? If i want to enter any variable instead of hard coded website name how to use above HYPERLINK() function?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how it can be done with variables instead. The double quotes are needed when you need to display a quote character within a string. Or, you can use `Chr(34)`.